# ssh-keyscan githib.com returned same public key

Tags: ssh

I tried ssh-keyscan on 2 of my different laptops.
One is using github ssh key, the other is not(using username/password).
The results turned out that I got same keys from this command(ssh-keyscan).

I even tried start a `node:alpine` container, also got the same result.
Can anyone tell me why?

Also want to be clear about that is there a default github public key when I ssh-keyscan?